# Why Java use hierarchical directories for packages?

Tags: java

I will try to explain my question with an example.

Lets say my application has 3 packages:

1. company.module_one
2. company.module_two
3. company.module_three

Directories will look like this in the file system:

company

```
   |- module_one
   |- module_two
   |- module_three
```

Why doesn't Java just create 3 directories for 3 packages? Like:

company.module_one

company.module_two

company.module_three

What does the directory hierarchy give us?

Comment: In file system it looks like the one you specified, if you view that in eclipse it will be displayed separately as you mentioned in your second scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It uses a tree for the same reason as you would create directories and directories in directories if you have a lot of files to store.

On the other hand I like the Package Explorer in Eclipse which presents the package tree as flat list.

But actually nothing in the Java Language Specification mandates to create hierarchical directories to store Java source code.

Comment: Yes, package explorer in Eclipse shows packages in a more meaningful way.